# 'Terminated due to time out'. Need help in optimising my code

Tags: c, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to implement dictionary. I would appreciate if you find the flaws in my code rather than changing whole logic.

Sample Input
3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry

Sample Output :
sam=99912222
Not found
harry=12299933

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Dict {
  char key[100];
  int value;
};

struct Dict *array;
int inputsize;

int getHashKey(char *key){
  return strlen(key)%inputsize;

}

void insert(char *key, int value){
  int i =0;
  int hashkey = getHashKey(key);

  /* Already inserted. Return */
  if(!strcmp (array[hashkey].key,key)){
   return;
  }

  /* Check if empty space. else, Get the next available space. */
  if(array[hashkey].value == 0){
    strcpy(array[hashkey].key,key);
    array[hashkey].value = value;  
  }else{ 
    hashkey++;
    while(array[hashkey].value!=0){
           hashkey++;
           /*if reached end of array. Re-start */
           if(hashkey == inputsize ){
           hashkey = 0;
           }
   }
   strcpy(array[hashkey].key,key);
   array[hashkey].value = value;
  }
}

void search(char *key){

 for(int i =0;i<inputsize;i++){    
    if(!strcmp(array[i].key,key)){
    printf("%s=%d\n",array[i].key,array[i].value);
    return;
    }
 }
 printf("Not found\n");
}



int main() {

  char key[100]; int value;
  scanf("%d",&inputsize);

  char *ptr[inputsize];

  //Initializing array pointer
  for(int i=0;i<inputsize;i++){
  ptr[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
  }

  array = (struct Dict *)malloc(sizeof(struct Dict)*inputsize);

  /*Reading Input.Key & value pair */
  for(int i=0;i<inputsize;i++){
  scanf("\n%20[^ ]",key);
  scanf("%d",&value);
  insert(key,value);
  }

  /*Reading Query */
  for(int i =0; i<inputsize;i++){
  scanf("%s",ptr[i]);
  } 

  /* Searching Query String in Dict */
  for(int i =0;i<inputsize;i++){
  search(ptr[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume that **terminate due to timeout** comes from some kind of online judge. Have you tested it locally and verified that it works on both the sample input and the largest input within the limits set out in the problem statement?

Comment: It's not a performance problem. You forgot to initialise your array, so your program is undefined.

Comment: I see no C++ here. If this is C, can we remove the C++ tag? If it's supposed to be C++, can we please use the STL instead of homebrew?

Comment: If your code is otherwise working correctly, I suppose you want to ask this on [codereview.se]. You may want to read their introductory [tour] though – I see you chose to skip that step for SO. Make sure to read their [On Topic Guide](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: On a side note, I am almost sure that `scanf("\n%20[^ ]",key);`  is a wrong way to read `key`.

Comment: @majk Yes,it is online judge problem. I tested it locally. It's working fine.

Comment: @molbdnilo Initialising array is not solving my problem.

Comment: If you add some prompts for input you'll notice that your program gets stuck before it reaches `insert`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Could you please explain through code ?                                   I was wrong. I should have initialised the array. I did later but still I am getting the timeout array.

Answer (score 5):

The following loop is never ending:

```
while (array[hashkey].value != 0) {
    hashkey++;
    /*if reached end of array. Re-start */
    if (hashkey == inputsize) {
        hashkey = 0;
    }
}
```

You have to review your algorithm to let it properly end.
The first thing you can do is to zeroed-out your array in order to be sure that it is properly initialized before using it. malloc is just allocating the memory. It is not performing any initialization for you.

```
array = (struct Dict *)malloc(sizeof(struct Dict)*inputsize);
memset(array, 0, sizeof(sizeof(struct Dict)*inputsize));
```

Comment: ...or use [calloc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm)

Comment: It isn't _never neding_ but [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: It's not never ending behaviour. However, I need a way to change this undefined behaviour. I will put the limit. I fixed this line of code. It didn't solve my problem. Btw thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be building a hash table, but when searching you perform a linear scan. This means that search is O(N) instead of close to O(1) when using linear hashing scheme.

Comment: I'm trying to get the free space if the key is similar in two separate cases so search cannot be O(1) in this case.